# Linear Algebra: Dimensionality of the Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was reading Gilbert Strangs book when I got to this quote:

"(Dimension of column space) + (dimension of nullspace) = dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$)"

I understand that dimension of column space is $r$, and dim null space is $n - r$. However, I do not know why he added $C(A) + N(A)$. I thought the whole point was to add the dims of $C(A) + N(AT)$ to get $m$? Aren't the column and the left null space perpendicular? I do not see why he emphasized this relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is finite dimensional, and $L:V\to W$ linear, then the rank-nullity theorem states that the $\rm{rank}(L)+\rm{null}(L)=\rm{dim}V$.

As to your other comment/question, the nullity of a square matrix and it's transpose are the same, by the theorem that the row rank equals the column rank, a.k.a. the *rank* of the matrix.